# radiobuttonlist alignment

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to make a radiobuttonlist appears horizontally with text on the bottom, in ASP.Net?

```
      .            .              .
   Option 1     Option 2      Option 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `RepeatDirection` attribute to `Horizontal`. This will only work if `RepeatLayout` is set to `Table`, which it is by default.

Comment: what about setting the text down the buttom rather than next to the bullet point?